# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-win32-x64-1.0.392 in java.library.path - gradle based javafx

Tags: java, netbeans, cloudant, sqlite4java

I'm working on a small gradle based javafx project using netbeans ide (win7). Everything works fine until i included cloudant-sync and sqlite4java, now i get UnsatisfiedLinkError whenever i run the project. Please how do i resolve this.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite4java-win32-x64-1.0.392 in java.library.path

See gradle.build and console output below:

> **gradle.build**
>
> apply plugin: 'java'
>
> sourceCompatibility = '1.8' [compileJava,
>   compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
>
> // NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on
>   the // "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior
>   executing // tasks by passing a "-PmainClass="
>   argument. // // Note however, that you may define your own "run" and
>   "debug" task if you // prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add
>   these tasks but you may rely on // your own implementation. if
>   (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
>       ext.mainClass = 'falcon3.Main' }
>
> repositories {
>       mavenCentral() }
>
> dependencies {
>       compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:1.1.0'
>       compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-javase', version:'2.0.0'
>       compile group: 'com.almworks.sqlite4java', name: 'sqlite4java', version: '1.0.392'
>       compile 'com.aquafx-project:aquafx:0.2'
>       testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10' }

and

> **console output**
>
> Executing: gradle run Arguments: [-c,
>   C:\Users\???\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Falcon3\settings.gradle]
>
> :compileJava UP-TO-DATE :processResources UP-TO-DATE :classes
>   UP-TO-DATE Feb 11, 2017 11:57:23 AM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal
>   log INFO: [sqlite] DB[1]: instantiated [null] Exception in Application
>   start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.internal.sqlite.SQLDatabaseQueue.(SQLDatabaseQueue.java:67)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.internal.documentstore.DatabaseImpl.(DatabaseImpl.java:152)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.documentstore.DocumentStore.(DocumentStore.java:90)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.documentstore.DocumentStore.getInstance(DocumentStore.java:150)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.documentstore.DocumentStore.getInstance(DocumentStore.java:120)
>     at falcon3.Main.start(Main.java:28)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to open
>   database.     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.internal.sqlite.sqlite4java.SQLiteWrapper.createNewConnection(SQLiteWrapper.java:92)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.internal.sqlite.sqlite4java.SQLiteWrapper.getConnection(SQLiteWrapper.java:73)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.internal.sqlite.sqlite4java.SQLiteWrapper.isOpen(SQLiteWrapper.java:121)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.internal.sqlite.sqlite4java.SQLiteWrapper.beginTransaction(SQLiteWrapper.java:126)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.internal.sqlite.SQLDatabaseFactory.isFtsAvailable(SQLDatabaseFactory.java:52)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.internal.sqlite.SQLDatabaseFactory.(SQLDatabaseFactory.java:45)
>     ... 15 more Caused by: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException:
>   [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   sqlite4java-win32-x64-1.0.392 in java.library.path    at
>   com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:97)   at
>   com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open0(SQLiteConnection.java:1441)
>     at
>   com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:282)
>     at
>   com.cloudant.sync.internal.sqlite.sqlite4java.SQLiteWrapper.createNewConnection(SQLiteWrapper.java:88)
>     ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   sqlite4java-win32-x64-1.0.392 in java.library.path    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)    at
>   com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.tryLoadFromSystemPath(Internal.java:352)
>     at com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal.loadLibraryX(Internal.java:124)
>     at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLite.loadLibrary(SQLite.java:95)  ...
>   23 more Exception running application falcon3.Main :run FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':run'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2.578 secs
>
> Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle
>   run

Answer (score 0):

sqlite4java is not a pure Java package, but needs a binary build of the actual SQLite library. This has to be available to the JVM at runtime. The sqlite4java documentation says:

> To start using sqlite4java, you only need to place sqlite4java.jar and platform-dependent binaries into a directory in the CLASSPATH. (Binaries should be in the same directory as the jar file.)

Try adding another dependency:

```
runtime group: 'com.almworks.sqlite4java', name: 'sqlite4java-win32-x64', version: '1.0.392'
```

Comment: I just included the runtime, but i still get the same error even after netbeans restart.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086207/3887715

Although the answer is based on DynamoDBLocal, you've already included the `sqlite4java` dependencies, so you should be able to get it working with a similar set-up.

You need to copy the library files to another directory:

```
task copyNativeDeps(type: Copy) {
    from(configurations.compile + configurations.testCompile) {
        include '*.dll'
        include '*.dylib'
        include '*.so'
    }
    into 'build/libs'
}
```

And then set the system property `sqlite4java.library.path` to the path to that directory. In my case, I needed it for a test, so I just added a initialiser block to my test class:

```
public class CreateDynamoDBTest {
    {
        System.setProperty("sqlite4java.library.path", "build/libs");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```